# Setting Default Image Dynamically Based On Model Choice - Django

Tags: python, django

Say I have a class:

```
imageModel(models.Model):
    O1 = 'Option1'
    O2 = 'Option2'

    CHOICES = (
        (O1, 'Option1'),
        (O2, 'Option2'),
    )

    options = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CHOICES)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

How would I dynamically set the default for the image field based on the option choice?

I tried something like:

```
imageModel(models.Model):
    O1 = 'Option1'
    O2 = 'Option2'

    CHOICES = (
        (O1, 'Option1'),
        (O2, 'Option2'),
    )

    options = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CHOICES)
    image = models.ImageField()

    def get_default_image(self):

       super().save()
       img = Image.open(self.company_logo.path)
       if self.options == "Option1":
          img.default = "/static/img/option1img.jpg"
       elif self.options == "Option2":
          img.default = "/static/img/option2img.jpg"
        img.save(self.image.path)
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the images are static, there are only two images and there may be a lot of records with only those two possible images.

I suggest you to do something like following

```
imageModel(models.Model):
    O1 = 'Option1'
    O2 = 'Option2'

    CHOICES = (
        (O1, 'Option1'),
        (O2, 'Option2'),
    )

    options = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CHOICES)
```

If the code is in `admin.py`

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

    @classmethod
    def thumbnail(self, obj):
        if obj.options == "option1":
            return mark_safe(
                '<img src="/static/img/option1img.jpg" width="75" height="auto" >'
            )
        else:
            return mark_safe(
                '<img src="/static/img/option2img.jpg" width="75" height="75" >'
            )
```